# Autocomplete function in combobox control

Tags: vb.net, autocomplete

I used `combobox` in vb.net 2008, I found that there is no **autocomplete mode** and **autocomplete source** function or property. Is there a way to suggest text in combo box control ?

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode(v=vs.90).aspx) it does support it.

Answer (score 0):

```
comboBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear()
comboBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add("YOUR STRING HERE")
```

Have you tried it?

Comment: In visual studio 2008, autocomplete source is not a member of system.windows.forms.combobox

Comment: @MDP it wouldn't be a matter of what version of IDE it supports - what .NET framework version are you using?

Comment: In that case it should still work, Visual Studio will hide certain properties, but they will still compile, try the code above and try compile, it should either work or say that it isnt a member of combobox.